# How to use django forms and javascript for autocompletion of field

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, autocomplete

I have a model that has fields like `name, place (address), lat, lon, hobby etc.`

In order to get these fields, I am using a form in Django. Something like this:

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["name", "place", "date","hobbies"]
        widgets = {
            'date': SelectDateWidget()
        }
```

I want to use the google maps api to enable autocompletion on filling the address from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

and read the lat/lon from the place address itself.

In my html, i render it like:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p}}
    {{ form.media }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit Post"/>
</form>
```

***However, I wonder how can I link the 'id' of the 'places' text box to the javascript action that enables autocompletion?***
Then I plan to use lat/lan as hidden field to populate their values, client side.

Is there a better way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Django renders form with id name something like `id_model_field_name`. If your model field name is `place`, in form the id of that field will be `id_place`. Using this id you can enable autocomplete javascript code.